# how to fetch metrics data from prometheus and use it within java springboot App?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory, prometheus

I want to create an Alarm when CPU memory/Hard Disk Memory is full. I am using spring-boot f/w along with Prometheus. I can view all metrics details on HTTP requests:- http://localhost:9090/actuator/prometheus. but IDK how can I fetch the data from Prometheus in my project to raise an alarm or to do any action.

your suggestion/links will be more valuable. Thank you.

Comment: Using prometheus or grafana's alerts would be more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can scrap metrics from your actuator endpiont in the same way as Prometheus do it.
I use OkHttpClient for that.
Example of my client:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                .followRedirects(false)
                .protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE))
                .build();
```

All settings are optional. But pay attention to the protocol - it should be the same as on your application's server.

After that you  need to build url:

```
String url = "http://localhost:9090/actuator/prometheus?includedNames=<nameOfThePropertyThatYouNeed>";
```

You can include here more than 1 property:

```
String url = "http://localhost:9090/actuator/prometheus?includedNames=<propertyNameOne>,<propertyNameTwo>,<propertyNameThree>";
```

After that you make request:

```
Request request =new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .get()
                .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
String responseBody = response.body().string();
```

Now you need to parse responseBody. Do it in the way as Prometheus does it and use classes of Prometheus:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody.getBytes())
CollectorPrometheusMetricsWalker walker = new CollectorPrometheusMetricsWalker();
PrometheusMetricsProcessor<MetricFamily> processor = new TextPrometheusMetricsProcessor(inputStream, walker);
processor.walk();
List<MetricFamily> metricList = walker.getAllMetricFamilies();
```

`MetricFamily` object stores all metrics with the same name but with different tags.
Use `metricFamily.getMetrics()` to get `List<Metric>`
Use `metric.getValue()` to get the value of metric.

Comment: Thanks, @Igor_M will try and update here.

Comment: Try, but as Sergio Santiago said, it's better to use AlarmManager. I used this approach as temporary solution

Comment: sure AlertManger as Sergio Santiago said, will be use-full, but we follow a different approach to raise alarm. so All I need is disk space data and CPU data.  I thought of adding my own methods to check disk Data. but as I was using Prometheus thought is there any easier way to fetch data from Prometheus metrics.

Comment: @Igor_M where do you get that Prometheus classes from?

Comment: @dchappelle <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hawkular.agent</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-scraper</artifactId>
            <version>0.23.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AlertManager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/) that is part of Prometheus suit.